# Indirect virtual base without a default ctor stops children from having a default ctor, unless every class in between also has one

Tags: c++

I'm sorry for the obscure title, not sure how to word it better.

Consider following inheritance hierarchy:

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {}
};

struct B : virtual A
{
    B() : A(42) {}
};

struct C : B
{
    C() : A(43) {}
};
```

It does work. Now let's say I want to create a template that can be transparently injected in the middle of a hierarchy, like this:

```
template <typename ...P>
struct Proxy : P...
{
    // This constructor doesn't change anything. It was added
    // to indicate that `Proxy` should only be used as a base.
  protected:
    Proxy() = default;
};

struct D : Proxy<B>
{
    D() : A(44) {}
};
```

This gives me: `error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Proxy<B>'`.

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++A(int)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B+:+virtual+A%0A%7B%0A++++B()+:+A(42)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+C+:+B%0A%7B%0A++++C()+:+A(43)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+...P%3E%0Astruct+Proxy+:+P...%0A%7B%0A++protected:%0A++++Proxy()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+D+:+Proxy%3CB%3E%0A%7B%0A++++D()+:+A(44)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.70048473853118,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1200,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:43.90048154093098,l:%274%27,m:42.22635163170616,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+12.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:57.77364836829384,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.29951526146883,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

I understand what's going on: `Proxy` can't have a default constructor, because it doesn't provide an initializer for `A`, hence the derived class can't default-construct `Proxy`.

But it doesn't make sense if you think about it, because even if I provided an initializer for `A` in `Proxy`, `D` would ignore it and would have to provide its own.

How can I work around this limitation?

Everything in code can be changed, but I'd prefer less invasive changes.

---

In my actual code, there's only one base class that causes those problems, so I made two different default constructors for `Proxy` (distinguished with `requires`): one doing nothing, and the other (which is used when any of `P...` virtually inherits from `A`) passing a dummy parameter to `A::A(int)`.

But I don't like this solution because it's not generic, so I'm looking for better alternatives.

Comment: Is adding a default constructor to `A` not feasible?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I'd prefer to not make it public, but making it private and be`friend`ing `Proxy` could be a viable option.

Comment: Does removing the explicitly-declared default constructor of `Proxy` make the compilation error go away?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nope. It's there just to indicate that `Proxy` should only be used as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[special]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/special#7):

> For a class, its non-static data members, its non-virtual direct base
> classes, and, if the class is not abstract ([class.abstract]), its
> virtual base classes are called its *potentially constructed
> subobjects*.

[[class.default.ctor]/2.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.default.ctor#2.7) says that a defaulted default constructor is defined as deleted if

> any potentially constructed subobject, except for a non-static data
> member with a brace-or-equal-initializer, has class type `M` (or array
> thereof) and either `M` has no default constructor or overload
> resolution ([over.match]) as applied to find `M`'s corresponding
> constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted
> or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor

So we can exclude virtual bases from the set of potentially constructed subobjects by making `Proxy` abstract, for instance by making the destructor pure virtual (but still supply a definition):

```
template <typename ...P>
struct Proxy : P...
{
  protected:
    virtual ~Proxy() = 0;
    Proxy() = default;
};

template <typename ...P>
Proxy<P...>::~Proxy() = default;
```